# Unable to remove all line breaks from string in PHP

Tags: php, whitespace

I've got a basic textarea form.  What i'm trying to do is remove all line breaks from the textarea after its been submitted.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php 
   if (isset ($_POST['comment_form_submit'])) {
    $body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['body']);

    $breaks = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
    $newtext = str_replace($breaks, "", $body);

    echo $newtext;
   }
?>
```

Now let say I when filling out the form I press Shift+enter, that creates a \n in my string, but after submitting the form, $newtext still equals "\n", shouldn't "\n" be removed because I'm replacing it with ""

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you're escaping the `\n` for MySQL first. Try this:

```
<?php 
   if (isset ($_POST['comment_form_submit'])) {
    $body = $_POST['body'];

    $breaks = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
    $newtext = str_replace($breaks, "", $body);

    $newtext = mysql_real_escape_string($newtext);

    echo $newtext;
   }
?>
```

Read about the escape function you're using to see why: http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Duh..ok. Can't believe I missed that..Thanks Cal.

Comment: **`"Warning`**
`This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."` [Source](http://br1.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below code,
Or copy paste the content in CK editor and replace the character which u want to replace...

```
 <?php
    $desc = trim(stripslashes($crw['Description']));
    $desc=str_replace(","," ",$desc);
    $desc=str_replace("\r\n"," ",$desc);
    $desc=str_replace("\n"," ",$desc);
    $desc=str_replace("<br>"," ",$desc);
    $desc=str_replace("<br />"," ",$desc);
    echo $desc; ?>
```